# Are Jews halachically allowed to go up toTemple Mount?

Tags: minhag

BS"D

May Jews go up to the Temple Mount? I"ve read some Rabbanim for and against.
I just found this source by Rav Dov Lior for allowing? Does anyone have a source for those against?
http://the--temple.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/blog-post_6.html

Comment: If they went to the Mikvah then they can visit the outer parts. This is basically indisputable.